# How to select the child object in Android Application using Appium

Tags: java, android, xpath, appium

I am new to Appium and started automating Android Mobile Application using Appium.
I am facing problem in **finding child objects (Screenshot 2)**
I have to **select the desired item highlighted on screenshot 2**. 
Can anyone help me to select the highlighted item in screenshot 2?

**Desired Object Name :** TextView
**Appium Version :** 1.4.16.1
**Eclipse Version:** 4.4.2
**Programming Language:** Java

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H94qq.png)

[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXT58.png)

Comment: Is it a drop down menu in your application.

Comment: Upon clicking a **down arrow from home page**,this **recycler view  gets displayed to the user to select an item**.